# Container height when rotating images with CSS3

Tags: css, rotation, image-rotation

I have to rotate an image inside a div. The div must be 100% of width and the image inside is 100% of width so I can not define a fixed height for the div.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="floorplan">
    <img alt="" src="http://dexpierta.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/memes-4-meme_00288337.png" />
</div>
```

I have tried two solutions:

- http://jsfiddle.net/MTyFP/7/
- http://www.benknowscode.com/2014/01/css-rotated-text-parent-dimensions-and-spacing-issues.html

But none of them works as needed. Does anyone have experience with rotating images? You can see a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/wcqepwar/

Comment: Please consider providing an online example to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: I have added a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/wcqepwar/